# Modelling Optimal Sorting Networks

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, constraint-programming

I am trying to find sorting networks having the optimal depth or optimal number of comparators by generating $2^n$ binary sequences where $n$ is the channel size.

The main variables in my model are as follows:

$L_{ijd} = 1$ if a comparator exists between indices $(i, j)$ at depth $d$ and $0$ otherwise.

$V_{idj}$ is the input value ($0$ or $1$)  at index $i$, depth $d$ for the $j^{th}$ binary_sequence.

My model is based on section 2 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6271). The issue I am finding with my model is that I've to input the value of depth $d$ that allows me to find the optimal depth. But that doesn't help in finding the optimal number of comparators.

Now I can just create depth as a variable but then it is used as an index. That's causing the issue. How can I change the model so that it allows the solver to find the depth?

Answer (score 1):

Say $D$ is a set/list/dictionary/dataframe of all possible $d$ values, defined parameter. Define binary set $z_d'$ where $d'$ is indexed over $D$. Then using constraint
$ \sum_{d' \in D} z_{d'} = d$

Then use $ \sum_{d'} z_{d'}D_{d'} V_{ij}^{d'}$